# Unable to build expression for 'inline-eval' : null'facts["XYZ"] == "ABC"'

Tags: java, mule, drools

When I have upgraded mule version `3.3.2` to `3.4.2` I am facing this issue for bpm rule engine.

```
drools 5.0.1
```

upgraded `spring` dependency also `3.2.1.RELEASE` , here is my drl :

```
#From row number: 13
rule "TEST Block Rule 1"

    salience 65523
    when
        dto: DroolsDTO(facts["XYZ"]=="ABC", facts["MESSAGE_ASC_FLAG"]=="Y")
    then
        dto.setState("PQR", "XYZ");
end
```

and equivalent mule entry:

```
    <foreach collection="#[groovy:flowVars.TAGS]" counterVariableName="TAG_IDX">
            <bpm:rules rulesDefinition="${drools.config.path}/Determination.xls.drl"
                    initialFacts-ref="NoFactsBean" doc:name="Fire Drools" />
</foreach>
```

This was working fine with 3.3.2, but giving this stack trace:

```
org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Errors while parsing ruleset defined in file drools/Determination.xls.drl : Unable to build expression for 'inline-eval' : null'facts["XYZ"] == "ABC"'
null : [Rule name='TEST Block Rule 1']
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you post your complete config.xml

Comment: @NaveenRaj Thanks for your response..issue has been fixed..this issue was with import java.util.regex.* ..when ever there is a import .* in the .drl the new version is not supporting...